# Libre Office Calc, search history missing

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu 20.04, Libre Office 6.4.7.2

Ubuntu 22.04, Libre Office 7.3.3.2

Libre Office Calc : With ctrl-f I will get the "search Box", type in something for search a.s.o.. Next string to search a.s.o..
In former Versions of Libre Office, there were always a "search string history" present (arrow down next to the box), but now the pull down box is always empty.

Is there any configuration possible to get the "search string history" as in former SW versions ?

Comment: Are all files in `~/.config/libreoffice` owned by your user, and user-writable?

Comment: I did check it, me and group have Read/write access. On another Ubuntu 22.04 new installed system, also there is no "search history".